# Я хочу сделать таймер на 5, 10 и 15 минут. Но после сворачивания программы мой таймер дальше не идет

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)fivemin:(id)sender{perVrem = 300;
    TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"05:00"];}
-(IBAction)tenmin:(id)sender{perVrem = 600;
    TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10:00"];}
-(IBAction)fifteen:(id)sender{perVrem = 900;
    TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"15:00"];}



-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{
    secondsCount = perVrem;
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}

-(IBAction)Stop:(id)sender{
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
}

-(IBAction)Reset:(id)sender{
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
    countdownTimer = nil;
    secondsCount = 0;
    TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:00"];
}

-(void)timeRun{
    secondsCount = secondsCount - 1;
    int minuts = secondsCount / 60;
    int seconds = secondsCount - (minuts * 60);
    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minuts, seconds];
    TimerDisplay.text = timerOutput;



    if (secondsCount == 0) {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
        countdownTimer = nil;

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID);
    }

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:@"pip" ofType: @"mp3"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge  CFURLRef) SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);

    self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-4103490159107800/4026951578";
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    [self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

В ios приложение в бэкграунде само не живёт. Вроде сейчас можно запросить максимум 3 минуты чтобы оно ещё висело, а если нужно больше - тут уже надо чтобы функционал приложения соответствовал задаче, которой разрешено висеть в бэкграунде дольше, например - трекинг локейшена или проигрывание музыки.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Чтобы получить свои законные три минуты можно написать такой под в апп делегате:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"Keep online" expirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        while (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
        }
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Comment: откуда взята информация про 3 минуты?

Comment: Экспериментально, из личного опыта, на старых осях было 10 минут, потом сократилось. Я ну думаю, что это время задокументировано, и по умолчанию может быть любым, на выбор оси, но по факту для каждой версии оси оно фиксировано, и для 9 оно было 3 минуты, если мне не изменяет память. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275415/how-long-does-apple-permit-a-background-task-to-run